# Choosing an implementation of a function with a given signature

Tags: haskell

I want have some piece of code where I want to call a function `foo` with different implementations of foo residing in different modules.

Like

```
foo :: String -> IO[String]
```

module A:

```
foo :: String -> IO[String]
foo x = whatever
```

module B:

```
foo :: String -> IO[String]
foo x = whatever (different)
```

and then call the appropriate function based on some parameter. I could do with qualified imports:

```
import qualified ModuleA as A
import qualified ModuleB as B

bar :: String -> String -> IO[String]
bar moduleToChoose x = case moduleToChoose of
    "A" -> A.foo x
    "B" -> B.foo x
    _ -> Uh oh...
```

This, however basically screams "There is a so much more elegant™ solution to this but you just don't get it!" Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why use `moduleToChoose` when you can directly pass the function? Can you do a `bar :: (String -> IO [String]) -> IO [String]` directly, and when you call the function later, just do a `baz <- bar A.foo x` wherever you need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modules aren't first class in Haskell, and so there is no way to use them directly as parameters. In any case, an improvement on your solution would be using a sum type to encode the distinction in a richer and safer way. That can feel pretty natural given meaningful names for modules, types and values (i.e., names that actually reflect what you are trying to do):

```
import qualified Formatting.Mimsy as Mimsy
import qualified Formatting.Slithy as Slithy

data FormattingStyle = Mimsy | Slithy

foo :: FormattingStyle -> String -> IO [String]
foo style x = case style of
    Mimsy  -> Mimsy.foo x
    Slithy -> Slithy.foo x
```

You *might* want to take this a step further and encode the case switch using a type class:

```
class Fooer a where
    foo :: a -> String -> IO [String]

data Mimsy = Mimsy

instance Fooer Mimsy where
    foo _ x = undefined -- etc.

data Slithy = Slithy

instance Fooer Slithy where
    foo _ x = undefined -- etc.
```

Another possibility is to use `newtype` wrappers around `String` and a `Fooable` class, akin to Lee Duhem's answer. Either way, using classes for that feels like overkill to me, so I'd stick with the simple sum type solution.

Yet another approach is using records of functions instead of type classes. That, too, is overkill here, though arguably less so than using classes:

```
data Fooer = Fooer { foo :: String -> IO [String] }

-- Export only mimsy and slithy, and not the Fooer constructor.

mimsy :: Fooer
mimsy = Fooer { foo = Mimsy.foo }

slithy :: Fooer
slithy = Fooer { foo = Slithy.foo }
```

Comment: I agree that every solution beyond the first one presented has some ring of overkill to it, so I went for that. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I would change `bar` to take the auxiliary funcion directly as a parameter, instead of using a selector parameter.

```
bar :: (String -> IO [String]) -> String -> IO [String]
```

Outside the function (possibly in my `Main.hs`) I would construct the following map:

```
strategies :: M.Map String (String -> IO [String])
strategies = M.fromList [("A",A.foo), ("B",B.foo)]
```

This map allows us to decouple the aggregation of the known implementations from the selection of what implementation to use.

The process of looking into the map and constructing the actual `bar' :: String -> IO [String]` function in which we are interested should be relegated to the outermost layers of your program. That way, dependencies are minimized and "strategy not found" errors are detected sooner.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought about using a map, too. But as I have a known number of implementations that won't change, this need not be. I also refactored the stuff to decouple the selection from passing the function.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is using user-defined typeclass, like this:

FooClass.hs

```
module FooClass (FooClass(..)) where

class FooClass a where
    bar :: a -> IO [String]
```

A.hs

```
module A where

import FooClass

data A = A String deriving (Show)

foo :: A -> IO [String]
foo (A s) = return ["A", s]

instance FooClass A where
    bar = foo
```

B.hs

```
module B where

import FooClass

data B = B String deriving (Show)

foo :: B -> IO [String]
foo (B s) = return ["B", s]

instance FooClass B where
    bar = foo
```

After all those code, you can use them like this:

t.hs

```
import FooClass
import A
import B

main = do
    a <- bar (A "bar")
    b <- bar (B "bar")
    putStrLn $ show (a, b)
```

Testing:

```
$ runhaskell t.hs
(["A","bar"],["B","bar"])
```

Comment: `A` and `B` would be best defined with `newtype` in this case.

Comment: @duplode In this specific case, yes, you are right. Thank you for point that out.